# my car not start in weather cold Mercedes a160 classic

Tags: mercedes-benz

My car is not running this situation from a while ago when the weather was cold I tried to change the battery but it did not work when I turn the key to the activation of the sound of nothing but the sound of what is the problem please

Comment: Was the replacement battery charged?

Comment: Yes Replace the battery with a new one